# How is this site different from the other site?

Tags: discussion, migration, scope, policy

In what ways is judaism.stackexchange.com different from the old mi.yodeya.com?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be more intentionally worded like the Pesach question, "Why is this night defferent from all the other nights?"

Comment: @Peter I made it as close as I could without straying from the meaning of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"What's different" depends on how deep you want to go.

There have been a few *fundamental* additions to the ecosystem of a Stack Exchange site.

- This meta forum — You own, dedicated [meta sites give you an opportunity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) to talk about the development, promotion, and governance of the Judaism Stack Exchange site.
- [The Judaism chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) — the chat rooms are designed to be a [third place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) for real time socialization and coordination of work.

Beyond that, there have been a bazillion other little behaviors and features added since the time of mi.yodeya — but, truthfully, the best way to find these features is to just use and enjoy the site. If you either need or want a particular feature, the system is designed to be discoverable.

If you have any *questions* about how to use a feature, this is the place to ask!

If you want to be a bit more proactive and follow the development of the Stack Exchange Network, the [Stack Exchange Blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) is the best place to read about the big-picture announcements.

If that doesn't provide enough detail, there is a "[Recent Feature
Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)" post that chronicles any notable changes to the Q&A engine.

Beyond that lies [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), which gets into the really nitty-gritty, insider-baseball stuff.

Answer (score 7):

This site is missing the big red warning on top — and I want it back!!

Comment: +1 Excellent point.

Comment: The "Big red warning" now appear in the right column of the site: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/cylor-disclaimer/59#59

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821.

Answer (score 5):

Some stuff I noticed:

- Obviously, the design of the entire site has changed. I personally like the old one better
- Users are now showing accept rates (and [see here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-mark-as-accepted))
- As a StackExchange 2.0 site we now have all the new technology like having @ replies in comments, alert users (a long-awaited feature)
- Reputation works a lot differently, but in a good way
- We now have a meta site!

And more to be updated as I continue to get used to the new site....

Comment: Regarding the design, it's intentionally rough-looking for the beta. Eventually, SE's graphic designer will work with the community to make a beautiful, fitting design. I like the looks of other graduated SE sites.

Answer (score 5):

One SE 2.0 feature I'm pretty excited about is [tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) [wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/). So many of [our tags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) refer to concepts that many people don't know too much about, so I think that the tags would be even more useful if they each had a little explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Isaac Moses no longer has two diamonds next to his name (for one).

Comment: And yet Isaac Moses has in no way diminished his dependability and involvement in the site!

Comment: @WAF It's hard to measure dependability with a sample size of a few hours. 8^) I hope everyone from mi.yodeya participates here at least as much as they did there.

Comment: He no longer has any, in fact. I think we'd love to give him some though.

Answer (score 4):

[Tag synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) are a boon we didn't have at the old site. We made do with adding synonyms into the tags themselves, as in [`writing-printing`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/writing-printing/). To-be-created tags need no longer do that: choose whichever of the words you like, and if someone creates a synonymous tag then the community can easily merge them so that future uses of either will work.

Comment: Absolutely, I think the entire set of existing tags should slowly be cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

This site has a moderation hierarchy (reminiscent of [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/faq)'s meta-moderation) in which regular users can "Review" new users' posts for potential flagging for more attention from moderators.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed more lag between clicking "post" and the post appearing. If this phenomenon exists it is a minor change.

Comment: Noticed it too: except the posts actually appear right away. To confirm, go to the "Questions" tab. It takes it about a minute to get on the "active" tab (which is the default tab when you go to the site). Not sure if it's by design or a database (technical thing)

Answer (score 2):

At least in this browser, it's impossible to select text in the preview version of an answer as you type it. (It was possible to do so in the old site.) This means that I can't type an escape sequence like *&mdash;* in the editing box, select the resulting character (in this case, an em dash) in the preview, copy it, and paste it back into the editing box in lieu of the escape sequence. I like the old version better in this regard.

Comment: This sounds like something to poste as a feature request here (as a new question) or in meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: @Isaac, since unselectability AFAIK requires deliberate coding, I assume it was done on purpose, and is considered a feature. (I can't imagine why, though.)

Comment: You may be able to dig up information about this on meta.SO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81712

Answer (score 1):

I can no longer remember what the font was on the old site, but this one has more severe *italics*. My browser identifies it as `Tahoma, Geneva, Arial`, which must have been the font family before as well, right?

EDIT: Looks like the old one was actually Trebuchet.