# The "Mark as Accepted"

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Are there any specific rules for accepting answers on Jewish Life & Learning? Like how to deal with two answers that are actually a Machlokes?

Also, I noticed that mi.yodeya (a.k.a. version 1.0) left out the accept rates for users. Was this done intentionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The display of the "accept rate" did not exist in the SE 1.0 version which ran the mi.yodeya site.

The premise of the accepted answer is that the author selects an answer they find *most* helpful. It doesn't *necessarily* imply that it is the *best* answer, or even the *correct* answer. It's just the original author's choice.

Answer (score 4):

I would add to @Robert's answer, and emphasize, that often a *wrong* answer will be accepted.
The question often comes up, how to deal with wrong accepted answers...

(see for example the answers to this [question on the Meta.Security site, "How do you avoid answers with ... flaws?"](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/128/33) It refers to technical issues there, but the same principles apply...)

Commenting, both to the answerer and to the OP, downvoting, and alternate answer, all can help fix this.
However, take into account that, as @Robert said, sometimes it's not about what is right, but about what is helpful. As you said, sometimes there are two correct, yet conflicting, answers.